# How to get the name of the immediate parent of a node in json through javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file stored externally in a directory. I need to parse the json file in javascript and get the immediate parents name of a known child element. This is my json file.

```
{
"name": "start",
"count": 67,
"criticality": "HIGH",
"label": "start",
"children": [{
    "name": "login",
    "count": 64,
    "criticality": "HIGH",
    "label": "login",
    "children": [{
        "name": "admin id",
        "count": 8,
        "criticality": "HIGH",
        "label": "admin id",
        "children": [{
            "name": "till & vault parameter maintenance",
            "count": 5,
            "criticality": "HIGH",
            "label": "till & vault parameter maintenance",
            "children": [{
                "name": "dedtvset",
                "count": 4,
                "criticality": "LOW",
                "label": "dedtvset"
            },
            {
                "name": "login",
                "count": 1,
                "criticality": "HIGH",
                "label": "login",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "checker id",
                    "count": 1,
                    "criticality": "LOW",
                    "label": "checker id"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "till & vault parameter summary",
            "count": 1,
            "criticality": "HIGH",
            "label": "till & vault parameter summary",
            "children": [{
                "name": "destvset",
                "count": 1,
                "criticality": "HIGH",
                "label": "destvset"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "arc summary",
            "count": 2,
            "criticality": "LOW",
            "label": "arc summary",
            "children": [{
                "name": "ifsatmmn",
                "count": 2,
                "criticality": "LOW",
                "label": "ifsatmmn"
            }]
        }]
    },
{
    "name": "open teller batch branch",
    "count": 2,
    "criticality": "LOW",
    "label": "open teller batch branch"
}]
```

if I have the name "dedtvset". Is there any way to get the immediate parents name "till & vault parameter summary"

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
function getPathToValue(haystack, needle, path) {
  if (haystack === needle) {
    return true
  } else if (typeof haystack === "object") {
    for (var key in haystack) {
      if (haystack.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (getPathToValue(haystack[key], needle, path)) {
          path.unshift(key)
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var path = []
getPathToValue(json, "destvset", path)
console.log(path)
// ["children", "0", "children", "0", "children", "1", "children", "0", "name"]
```

This gives you the complete path to the first element with the given value. However, you are looking for the value of a label, and then using that to find the name of the most recent label before that. But perhaps this will give you a starting point.

Comment: This gives the path from the start of JSON. But I need the immediate parent name, given the child name.

Comment: The item you said you are looking for is `"dedtvset"`. In your object, this is a value, not the name of a key. The name of the immediate parent of this label is `"children"`. I understand that you are really looking for the value of the `label` that is at the same level as the parent of the `label` whose value is `"dedtvset"`. If you can define your query precisely, then it is easier to find the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var parents = [];
    function findParent(data, childName) {
        if (data == null || childName == null) {
            console.log("No Input");
            return "";
        }
        var localChild = null;
        localChild = getValidChild(data);
        if(localChild != null){
            for (var i in localChild) {
                var child = localChild[i];
                if (typeof child != 'undefined' && child.name == childName) {
                    populate += "<option value='" + data.name + "'>"
                            + data.name + "</option>";
                    parents.push(data);
                }

                findParent(child, childName);
            }
        }
    }
    function getValidChild(data){
            if(typeof data.children != null && data.children != null){
                return data.children;
            }else if(typeof data._children != null && data._children != null){
                return data._children;
            }
          return null;
        }
```

This gives the immediate parent of the child. If there are two childs with the same name, it populates the two parents and add push it into an array.